# restFull web service method

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, web-services, jersey

I want to pass like a parameter an Array to RESTful webservice with Jersey. I have one mutiple select form where users can select multiple options. Then i pass the selected values using AJAX to the RESTful webservice.

That's the select:

```
<select id="u" multiple class="form-control">                       
 <option value="1">1</option>                   
 <option value="2">2</option>                   
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The jquery js:

```
$('#send').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/pc/ws/ms/save-options",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                ur: $('#u').val()
            }
        });
    });
```

I don't know how to indicate on the web service method receive is a array

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven and Jersey we can maybe add this maven dependency which include Jackson lib :

```
<properties>
    ...
    <dependency.jersey.version>1.18.1</dependency.jersey.version>
    ...
</properties>
```

+

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and a code similar to this one (not tested !) would maybe do the trick :

```
@POST
@Path("/save-options")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMyValues(Collection<Integer> values) {
    // Do whathever I want with my values
    ...
}
```